# Is there a way to Run Cordova app in ios simulator from visual studio 2017 on my windows 8

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova

I've been trying to run my application in ios mode but gives the error below but works for android simulator. I'm using VS 2017 on windows 8.

ERROR BLD706: A remote iOS build agent has not been configured. Configure one in Tools > Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > iOS Configuration. For details and alternatives see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=511904

I followed the microsoft link but the illustration is for Mac users

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying run the command $ cordova emulate ios, you need to have Xcode installed, which is only avaible on Mac OS.